# why does `datetime` module behave this way with timezones?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to work with time and timezones. I am in the `US/Mountain` time zone and my computer (Windows) is configured to that time zone.

```
import datetime
import zoneinfo

utc = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('UTC')
mt = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Mountain')

print(datetime.datetime.now())
print(datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(mt))
print(datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(utc))

# 2023-10-27 13:17:18.840857
# 2023-10-27 13:17:18.840857-06:00
# 2023-10-27 19:17:18.840857+00:00
```

The last line is the one that confuses me. I thought the code `datetime.datetime.now()` creates a timezone naive object, then `astimezone(utc)` converts it to a timezone aware object, but doesn't change the "value" of the time. But here you can see that `astimezone(utc)` causes 6 hours to be added to the value of the time, as if the time generated by `datetime.datetime.now()` was a mountain time object.

Comment: So you don't think that `2023-10-27 13:17:18.840857-06:00` and `2023-10-27 19:17:18.840857+00:00` represent the same time in different time zones?

Comment: What's wrong? Your naive time is the same as your local time, so UTC is off by 6 hours.

Comment: @Corralien Are naive datetimes assumed to be in the local timezone? I thought naive objects had "no" timezone associated.

Comment: What native time, time without time zone, even mean? In this scenario, I assume `datetime` chooses the system timezone as the default

Comment: @Jagerber48. No, there is no associated time zone for a naive date/time, but if you decide to convert it to an aware date/time, your local time zone is used by default. If you want to specify how to interpret the naive datetime, use `replace` instead of `astimezone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs on `astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

> Return a datetime object with new tzinfo attribute tz, adjusting the date and time data so the result is the same UTC time as self, but in tz’s local time.
>
> If provided, tz must be an instance of a tzinfo subclass, and its utcoffset() and dst() methods must not return None. If self is naive, it is presumed to represent time in the system timezone.
>
> ...
>
> If you merely want to attach a time zone object tz to a datetime dt without adjustment of date and time data, use `dt.replace(tzinfo=tz)`. If you merely want to remove the time zone object from an aware datetime dt without conversion of date and time data, use `dt.replace(tzinfo=None)`.

I get the expected behavior if I use `replace`:

```
import datetime
import zoneinfo

utc = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('UTC')
mt = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Mountain')

print(datetime.datetime.now())
print(datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=mt))
print(datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc))

# 2023-10-27 13:45:35.897159
# 2023-10-27 13:45:35.897159-06:00
# 2023-10-27 13:45:35.897159+00:00
```

What was happening in my code is that when I use `astimezone()` the `datetime` modules DOES infer a timezone from my system time and then uses that to convert the time to the SAME `utc` time. `replace` is the function to use to just "drop in" a timezone without making adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not in what `.now()` does which is, indeed, returning a naive timezone with no `tzinfo`, but in what `.astimezone` does when the date provided is naive.

The `.astimezone` method will look up your local (your computer's timezone) and use that for naive datetimes.

```
        mytz = self.tzinfo
        if mytz is None:
            mytz = self._local_timezone()
            myoffset = mytz.utcoffset(self)
```

[Link to current code in GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7d57288f6d0e7fffb2002ceb460784d39277584a/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L2011-L2014)

So it will (sort-of/kinda/lots-of-buts) behave as if you had provided a datetime localized to your computer's configured timezone.